# Can we add column to typed table in PostgreSql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Created a type vehicle as-

```
create type vehicle as ( tag text, name text);
```

Create table using type as-

```
create table bike of vehicle;
```

Trying to add column as-

```
alter table bike add column attributes text;
ERROR:  cannot add column to typed table
```

Is it possible to add column in typed column by any method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for [ALTER TYPE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-altertype.html)

> `CASCADE`
> Automatically propagate the operation to typed tables of the type being altered, and their descendants.

So, using your example:

```
CREATE TYPE vehicle AS ( tag text, name text);
CREATE TABLE bike OF vehicle;
INSERT INTO bike(tag, name) values ('t','n')
ALTER TYPE vehicle ADD ATTRIBUTE test text CASCADE;
SELECT * FROM bike
```

results in:

```
|tag|name|test|
|---|----|----|
|t  |n   |    |
```